# split string become custom code in crystall report

Tags: string, vb6

i have string like this

P-123C automatic
P-H342 non automatic system
P-HH231 automatic system
PD 4357JP
REF-B130MK3 air system
BSC-WDB801 flow system

and i want that string like this

P-123C
P-H342
P-HH231
PD 4357JP
REF-B139MK3
BSC-WDB801

Please help...master

Comment: The source string is constant or variable? If it's constant, then you can use Split() function to create an array of strings, separate by a space, next make a loop to select only the strings which start with P, R and B. If it's variable then become hard...

Comment: how it's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried, unfortunately PD 4357JP make problem because is separate by a space. Then because your result seem to be compose by upper chars and digit only, I've try to remove all lower chars, the result seem to be good:

```
Dim sOut As String
Dim sIn As String
Dim sResult As String
Dim i As Long
Dim c As String
sIn = "P-123C automatic P-H342 non automatic system P-HH231 automatic system PD 4357JP REF-B130MK3 air system BSC-WDB801 flow system"
For i = 1 To Len(sIn)
    c = Mid$(sIn, i, 1)
    Select Case Asc(c)
        Case 97 To 122 ' remove lower chars
            ' do nothing
        Case Else
            sOut = sOut & c
            sOut = Replace$(sOut, "  ", " ")
    End Select
Next i
sResult = sOut
Debug.Print sResult
'Is: P-123C P-H342 P-HH231 PD 4357JP REF-B130MK3 BSC-WDB801
```

Comment: if the characters in lowercase are constans, you can create an array with them and delete them from the original string.

Comment: how if the characters like this P-123C Automatic P-H342 Non Automatic System P-HH231 Automatic System PD 4357JP REF-B130MK3 Air System BSC-WDB801 Flow System how the code

Comment: @axna2000: then my code doesn't work properly, I think that what you want isn't possible, as this conditions. The source string should be formatted with a logical type. But isn't.

Comment: yes i know, the source must be constant first then your code i think work..thanks Giorgio